# Changing an objects class and saving it's change in `localstorage`

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, local-storage

I have hundreds of buttons. When the page loads these buttons have a star appended to them. This star will indicate which one is favorited or not based off of a click on that star.

I want the star to change to a "fav" star, when it's clicked, and then "unfav" when clicked again, and so on. Then, saved in local storage. Now, it does not switch. Instead it changes the class of the button rather than the favorite star.

How to resolve this?

In addition, the button would also be brought to the top of the list when favorited so it is more visible.

I have started with this code:

```js
// give buttons a star and give it a unique ID for changing
var img = new Image();
var buttons = [...document.getElementsByClassName('myButton')];
img.src = 'icons/buttons/fav.png';

img.onload = function () {
    buttons.forEach(button => {
        img.id = button.id + 'butfav';
        button.innerHTML += img.outerHTML;
    });
};
img.classList.add('fav');
img.setAttribute("href", "#");
img.setAttribute("title", "Favorite");

// favorite  code

// get favorites from local storage or empty array
var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites')) || [];
// add class 'fav' to each favorite
favorites.forEach(function(favorite) {
  document.getElementById(favorite).className = 'fav';
});
// register click event listener
document.querySelector('.myButtons').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var id = e.target.id,
      item = e.target,
      index = favorites.indexOf(id);
  // return if target doesn't have an id (shouldn't happen)
  if (!id) return;
  // item is not favorite
  if (index == -1) {
    favorites.push(id);
    item.className = 'unfav';
  // item is already favorite
  } else {
    favorites.splice(index, 1);
    item.className = 'fav';
  }
  // store array in local storage
  localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
});

// local storage stores strings so we use JSON to stringify for storage and 
parse to get out of storage
```

```css
.myButton {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    font-family: 'coda';
    width: 45.5%;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 5px grey;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid #FFFFFF 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: .2s;
}
.fav {
    all: initial;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: +20;
}
.unfav {
    all: initial;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    content:url("icons/buttons/unfav.png")
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="buttons">
<div id="container">
<div id="musicmemes" class="music_container">
<span><a href="#" class="myButton" id="sound1">Sound 1</a></span>
<span><a href="#" class="myButton" id="sound2">Sound 2</a></span>
<span><a href="#" class="myButton" id="sound3">Sound 3</a></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question? With which part do you need help?

Comment: Good point, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Yes, switching it and saving that switch action is what I want to accomplish.

Comment: How come you are adding your `.fav` class to your `img`s? In your click handler shouldn't you be changing the images, e.g. altering between fav.png and unfav.png, which you initially place each of your buttons?

Comment: I wasn't aware of how to do that, especially since I had all these images with different IDs